# Calling async function within another fails, yet code execution continues, no error caught in try catch

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I'm very confused. I have an async function, I call another function within, when that fails, the error appears in browser console but main function contiues.

This function below fails, I see error in browser console log:

```
async function create (newContact)  {
    try {
        const request =  await axios.post(baseUrl, newContact);
        return request.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Failed to create contact. Error: ${error}`)
    }
}
```

I call that function in another function below. The post request definitely gets 400 response with error, yet the code in this function below continues without error (See Else Statement). Why?

```
async function addPerson (event) {
    try {
      event.preventDefault();
      const newPerson = {
        name : newName,
        number: newNumber
      }
      const person = searchPeople(newName);
      if (person !== -1) {
        if (window.confirm(`${newName} is already added to phonebook, replace the old number with a new one?`)) {
          const updatedContact = await contactsService.update(persons[person].id, newPerson);
          setPersons(persons.concat(updatedContact));
          setMessage({text: `Updated ${newName}`, type: 'notification'}) 
        }
      } else {
        const newContact = await contactsService.create(newPerson);
        // console.log("NEW: ", newContact);
        setPersons(persons.concat(newContact));
        setMessage({text: `Added ${newName}`, type: 'notification'}) 
      }
      setNewName('')
      setNewNumber('')
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage({text: `Error: ${error}`, type: 'error'}) 
    }
  }
```

Browser output:

```
Failed to create contact. Error: Error: Request failed with status code 400 contacts.js:18:16
NEW:  undefined
```

Yet despite create() failing, the success message on Front-End appears because code execution doesn't stop.

Comment: Two questions, 1. is `searchPeople()` synchronous, and 2. What's the error you mention?

Comment: @JeremyThille searchPeople() is just a map function. Error in create() is caught but doesn't get caught in addPerson().

Comment: If `searchPeople()` is a `.map()` function, why would it return `-1`? map returns an array, not a number

Comment: `const searchPeople = (name) => {
      return persons.map(person => person.name).indexOf(name);
  }`

Comment: I have no issues with searchPeople.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create()` call doesn't fail. You caught and logged the error, then returned `undefined`. The execution of `addPerson` continues unaffected - there's no exception thrown to be handled.

So either don't catch the error if you cannot handle it

```
async function create (newContact)  {
    const request =  await axios.post(baseUrl, newContact);
    return request.data;
}
```

or rethrow an exception

```
async function create (newContact)  {
    try {
        const request =  await axios.post(baseUrl, newContact);
        return request.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to create contact. Error: ${error}`);
    }
}
```